# Relation of a subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi I know a subset is a relation, but I am having trouble interpreting the relation.

If $A=\{a,b,c\}$ then the set of all relations on $A$ would be

$A \times A=\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,c),(b,b),(c,c),(c,b),(c,a)\}$

Since $R\subseteq A \times A$, a relation has to be a subset of the set $A \times A$

But which subset of $A \times A$ would be the **subset** relation on A?

Or does this mean we can only define a **subset** relation on $\mathcal{P}(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the set of all relations in $A$ are subsets of $A\times A$, that is, are in $\mathcal{P}(A\times A)$.

Comment: Does this mean that an element of the relation would be something like $(\{(b,b)\},\{(b,b),(c,c)\})$ ?

Comment: since $\{(b,b)\} \subseteq \{(b,b),(c,c)\}$

Comment: Yes, even the relation $ A \times A $ is an element of that set.

Comment: But does that mean the relation is on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and not $A$? Or is there a subset relation on both $A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$? Im sorry if you don't understand the question, but it was a problem in the book im practicing

Comment: Also would the set $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A)$ be the same set as  $\mathcal{P}(A \times A)$

Comment: No, so it says, a relation in $ A $ is just a subset $R\subseteq A\times A$. So, the set of all relations in $A$ must be...

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(A \times A)?$

Comment: A subset $S\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)\times \mathcal{P}(A)$ it will be said that it is *a relation in* $\mathcal{P}(A)$. And no, in principle, the sets $\mathcal{P}(A\times A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)\times \mathcal{P}(A)$ are not the same.

Comment: So if the subset relation were a relation on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ then the set of all relations on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ would be  $\mathcal{P}( \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A))$?

Comment: That's right! ...

Answer (score 0):

The subset relation is a relation between sets. Now the elements of $A$ may be sets, but you didn't specify anything about them, so it is not possible to say anything concrete about a subset relation between them. However, we can write it down abstractly:
$$R = \{(x,y)\in A\times A: x\subseteq y\}$$

Now if you specify specific sets as elements of $A$, then you can also write down the elements of the subset relation on $A$ explicitly. For example, say $a=\emptyset$, $b=\{u\}$, $c=\{v\}$. Then $A=\{\emptyset,\{u\},\{v\}\}$ and the corresponding subset relation reads
$$\{(\emptyset,\emptyset),(\emptyset,\{u\}),(\emptyset,\{v\}),(\{u\},\{u\}),(\{v\},\{v\})\}$$